# NestJS: HttpService is not mocked or found within unit-test

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, axios, mocking, nestjs

I'm attempting to write a unit test for a `@nestjs` service and need to mock the `HttpService`. My unit test implementation is returning with the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')`

Within the context of the unit test, httpService is never being defined despite the `@Injectable` decorator being used within the `air-gateway.service` module.

###### air-gateway.service.spec.ts

```
import { AirGatewayService } from './air-gateway.service';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { createMock, DeepMocked } from '@golevelup/ts-jest';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';

describe('AirGateway Service', () => {
  let service: AirGatewayService;
  let httpService: DeepMocked<HttpService>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AirGatewayService,
        {
          provide: HttpService,
          useValue: createMock<HttpService>(),
        },
      ],
    })
      .useMocker(createMock)
      .compile();

    service = await module.get<AirGatewayService>(AirGatewayService);
    httpService = await module.get(HttpService);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Here is the implementation of the service. I can confirm that is is successfully making calls to the endpoint within my developer environment.

###### air-gateway.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { TerminusArgs } from './dto/terminus.args';
import { AirSchedules } from './models/air-schedules.model';

@Injectable()
export class AirGatewayService {
  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}

  public async findAll(terminusArgs: TerminusArgs): Promise<AirSchedules> {
    const { data } = await firstValueFrom(
      this.httpService
        .get<GatewayResponse<AirSchedules>>(gatewayURL.href, { headers })
        .pipe(
          catchError((error: AxiosError) => {
            throw `GatewayServiceError -> findAll: an error has occurred fetching for Gateway\n${error}`;
          })
        )
    );
  }
}
```

- I have updated dependencies for anything nest, axios, jest, typescript up to recent versions.
  `"@nestjs/apollo": "12.0.3",`
  `"@nestjs/axios": "^3.0.0",`
  `"@nestjs/core": "10.0.3",`
  `"typescript": "5.1.6",`
- I have the babel.config.js for my project to allow me to run typescript within my tests

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
    '@babel/preset-typescript'
  ],
  plugins: [['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { version: '2023-11' }]]
};
```

- Tried setting up and removing the `jest.config.js` file as such:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    axios: 'axios/dist/node/axios.cjs'
  }
}
```

- Experimented with the `@automock/jest` npm package
  But this just fails for pretty much the same error just expressed differently within the error logs.

###### Automock snippet

```
  let service: AirGatewayService;
  let httpService: jest.Mocked<HttpService>;

  beforeAll(() => {
    const { unit, unitRef } =
      TestBed.create(AirGatewayService).compile();

    service = unit;
    httpService = unitRef.get(HttpService);
  });
```

Fails with:
IdentifierNotFoundError: Missing class dependency identifier (code ER010)
The dependency associated with the specified token or identifier ('HttpService') could not be located within
the current testing context. This issue pertains to the usage of the UnitReference API.
Please ensure accurate spelling and correspondence between the provided token or identifier and the corresponding
injection configuration. If you are utilizing a custom token, it is essential to confirm its proper registration
within the DI container

- I get this trace when running `npx jest air-gateway.service.spec.ts` with tracing enabled.

```
Trace: gateway
        at GatewayService.trace [as findAll] (/Users/pingwinZloty/Projects/centrus-active/apps/gateway-subgraph/src/gateway/gateway.service.ts:41:9)
        at Object.findAll (/Users/pingwinZloty/Projects/centrus-active/apps/gateway-subgraph/src/gateway/tests/gateway.service.spec.ts:140:35)
        at Promise.then.completed (/Users/pingwinZloty/Projects/centrus-active/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:298:28)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at callAsyncCircusFn (/Users/pingwinZloty/Projects/centrus-active/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:231:10)
        at _callCircusTest (/Users/pingwinZloty/Projects/centrus-active/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:316:40)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
        at _runTest (/Users/pingwinZloty/Projects/centrus-active/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:252:3)
        at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (/Users/pingwinZloty/Projects/centrus-active/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:126:9)
        at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (/Users/pingwinZloty/Projects/centrus-active/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:121:9)
        at run (/Users/pingwinZloty/Projects/centrus-active/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:71:3)
        at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (/Users/pingwinZloty/Projects/centrus-active/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapterInit.js:122:21)
        at jestAdapter (/Users/pingwinZloty/Projects/centrus-active/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapter.js:79:19)
        at runTestInternal (/Users/pingwinZloty/Projects/centrus-active/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:367:16)
        at runTest (/Users/pingwinZloty/Projects/centrus-active/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:444:34)
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace here?

Comment: I don't know how to do that without the formatter on StackExchange giving me a hard time.

I added it, but it looks very ugly

Comment: At this point, I genuinely think there is nothing wrong with the code itself. I'm wondering if there is some kind of special configuration needed to correctly test HttpService. There doesn't seem to be adequate documentation on this from either the nest or ts-jest documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try mocking using overrideProvider

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  providers: [
    AirGatewayService,HttpService
  ],
})
  .overrideProvider(HttpService)
  .useValue(mockHttpService)
  .compile();
```

You can mock your HttpService like this

```
export const mockHttpService ={
  get: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
     return ;
  }),
}
```

Comment: I tried it, it fails with the same error. For some strange reason, within the execution context of jest, httpClient is just always appearing as undefined.